# app crash on low performance devices when loading number of images

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter app crash when loading a large number of images. (app crash only low-performance devices. ex: Xiaomi 9c 2GB). I tried both `FadeInImage.memoryNetwork` and `CachedNetworkImage`.

Is there any better API to load network images without any issues?

Sometimes length more than 1000, sometimes length is 20-30. always crash on low-performance devices

```
SliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(),
      childCount: model.length,
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
                 return AspectRatio(
                   aspectRatio: childAspectRatio,
                   child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                              placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                              image: model[index].imageUrl,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover),

                            //   CachedNetworkImage(
                            //     placeholder: (context, url) => Container(),
                            //     errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>Container(),
                            //     imageUrl: model[index].imageUrl,
                            //     fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            //   )
```

**Updated:** check my comment

Comment: I see there's an open issue addressing the case. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50024
Related to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21571 and  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my own way to fix this crash issue on low-performance devices. please give me your feedback

```
FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
    placeholder: kTransparentImage,
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
    imageCacheHeight: 50, //adding these two parameters
    imageCacheWidth: 50,
    image: url,
)
```

Comment: please provide your ktransparentimae.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_image

Answer (score 0):

clear your app cache at every 10-15 sec. it's work for me.

refrence:- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager

```
await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
```

Comment: This is not a feasible solution to handle this issue

Answer (score 0):

`ExtendedImage` is a great one to use that helps with memory problems.

```
https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image
```

You can set `maxBytes` to 50 << 10, which means 50kb at max size, then the SDK lowers the image quality by itself and it helps with memory problems.
And `clearMemoryCacheWhenDispose` clears the memory automatically when the image widget is disposed from the widget tree.

Answer (score -1):

The better way would be to load fewer images at the start by using pagination. Loading such a large amount of images would be hard for old devices at once so the better approach would be to load like 50 images and on reaching the end of the screen load the next 50. In this way, the load would be maintainable even for lower-end devices.

Comment: please check my question again. I edited. Sometimes length more than 1000, sometimes length is 20-30. always crash on low-performance devices

Comment: not working wrong solution.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try using a different Isolate to load the images in a future and in parallel keep doing other work and waiting for the isolate to work.

You can use something like this

```
//start retrieving image here as a future
getImage(imgUrl).whenComplete((){}).then((value){
build the image using either CachedNetworkImage or FadeInImage.memeoryNetwork...

});

//call the isolate function

Future getImage(imgUrl) async{
  return compute(downloadImage, imgUrl);
}


downloadImage(imgUrl){
// get image here
// return image here

}
```